# Query To retrieve Desc. From Id In Linq

Tags: linq

I m new in Linq and i didnt understang this query

```
Db.Enum_Countries .Where(p=>p.id==id)
.Single()
.Title)
```

Can you help me....

Comment: You do have an extraneous ")" character at the end.  Is this really the correct snippet that you're looking at?

Answer (score 0):

`Where(...)` finds all the countries with the given id. `Single(...)` ensures that only one country has that id, and returns just that country.

In summary, it means, "The title of the only country whose id is `id`".

Comment: Just wanted to add for clarity that there MUST be EXACTLY ONE country.  If there are zero, or 2 or more, then an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of things -- presumably countries -- which have a `Title` property.  You want to find the single item in that list whose `id` property matches the `id` variable you have in scope.  Then you want to access its `Title` property.

You could also write:

```
db.Enum_Countries.Single(p => p.id == id).Title
```